# Run async method iterations (with nested iterations) indefinitely

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core

I'm trying to come up with the best way to run iterations of async methods.
Basically, I'm given a 1st `TimeSpan` and a `Dictionary<Item,TimeSpan>` to run within the first timespan.

For example:

```
var iteration = new TimeSpan().FromSeconds(60);

var items = new Dictionary<Item,TimeSpan>();
items.Add(item1,new TimeSpan().FromSeconds(10))
items.Add(item2,new TimeSpan().FromSeconds(30))
```

It is safe to assume that:

- `TimeSpan` of items in the dictionary is always `<` than `iteration`
- `iteration`, when converted to seconds, always fits `N` of `TimeSpan` of items in the dictionary (if iteration is 60 seconds than the timespans for items will be either 1 or 2 or 3 or 6 or 10 or 15 and so on.

For each `Item` I need to run an asynchronous method every `X` ms (as defined by the `TimeSpan` in the dictionary. For example:

```
public async Task<int> MyMethod(Item item)
{
    return await 3; // In reality something is done and a result is returned
}
```

Which means that for the two items in the example and the 60-second timespan, if I start at `T00:00` I need to run `MyMethod` for `item1` 6 times (at `T00:00`, `T00:10`, `T00:20` and so on) and for `item2` 2 times (at `T00:00` and at `T00:30`).

Now, this portion is relatively simple, what I'm struggling with a bit is making the `iteration` repeat again in 60 seconds and make sure it starts whether the previous one is completed or not. For example, if `MyMethod` for `item1` takes 12 seconds to complete I still want to start another iteration after `60` seconds (which means that at a certain point in time I will have more than one execution of `MyMethod` for `item1` active.

---

Something I was trying to do is a recursive `void` call to `MyMethod` with `ContinueWith(() => { MyMethod(item)` but could not get it to work.

Comment: Did you try Rx with timers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually solved the problem myself.
`Iteration` is a class that represents an iteration:

```
public void RunIterations()
{
    var iterations = new List<Iteration>();

    // Adding items that represent the iterations to run

    // Here we're creating an array of tasks for each iteration
    // The running RunIteration for each iteration that needs to be created
    // However, the tasks will never finish unless the cancellation is requested (as we can see in RunIteration method).
    var iterationTasks = new Task[iterations.Count];

    var iterationIndex = 0;
    foreach (Iteration iteration in iterations)
    {
        iterationTasks[iterationIndex] = RunIteration(iteration);
        iterationIndex++;
    }

    Task.WaitAll(iterationTasks);
}

private async Task RunIteration(Iteration iteration)
{
        // We're creating an endless loop that will keep starting the RunAsync() for the iteration until the cancellation is requested.
        while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // We're running the RunAsync() without waiting for it to finish.
            // It's done on purpose: in case any stages in the iteration take more time than expected
            // then another iteration is started in parallel as the previous one is finishing.
            iteration.RunAsync().ContinueWith(
                task => {
                    DoSomethingWithResult(task.Result);
                });

            // Waiting for the duration of the iteration to start the next one.
            await Task.Delay(( new TimeSpan().FromSeconds(60));
        }
}
```